# R: Install cplexAPI errors

Tags: r, compilation, cplex

I am trying to use cplexAPI in R. I am getting persistent errors. I am using Microsoft R Open 3.3.1 and have installed IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Version: 12.7.0.0 on Windows 10. Here is what I have done, and what has resulted. I am going to go into painstaking detail on the hope that you see my error somewhere!

1. Unpacked the tar file to a folder on my desktop.
2. Edit the file: `C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI\src\Makevars.win` to say:

`PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"$C:\Program  Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"
    PKG_LIBS=-L"$C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\lib" -lm -lcplex1270`

3. Microsoft put their own spin on the `Reviron.site` file. They put `Rcmd_environ` in: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-3.3.1\etc\Rcmd_environ`
   Within that file I added the bottom three lines:

`## from R.sh
    R_SHARE_DIR=${R_HOME}/share
    R_INCLUDE_DIR=${R_HOME}/include
    R_DOC_DIR=${R_HOME}/doc
    R_ARCH=
    ## from Rcmd
    R_OSTYPE=windows
    TEXINPUTS=.;${TEXINPUTS};${R_SHARE_DIR}/texmf/tex/latex;
    BIBINPUTS=.;${BIBINPUTS};${R_SHARE_DIR}/texmf/bibtex/bib;
    BSTINPUTS=.;${BSTINPUTS};${R_SHARE_DIR}/texmf/bibtex/bst;
    ## from etc/Renviron
    # R_PLATFORM='i386-pc-mingw32'
    R_PAPERSIZE_USER=${R_PAPERSIZE}
    R_PAPERSIZE=${R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'}
    # for Rd2dpf, reference manual
    R_RD4PDF=${R_RD4PDF-'times,inconsolata,hyper'}
    ## used for options("texi2dvi")
    # R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'texi2dvi'}}
    ## used by INSTALL, check, build
    R_GZIPCMD=${R_GZIPCMD-'gzip'}
    ## Default zip/unzip commands
    R_UNZIPCMD=${R_UNZIPCMD-'unzip'}
    R_ZIPCMD=${R_ZIPCMD-'zip'}
    R_BZIPCMD=${R_BZIPCMD-'bzip2'}
    ## Default browser
    # R_BROWSER=${R_BROWSER-'open'}
    ## Default editor
    # EDITOR=${EDITOR-${VISUAL-vi}}
    ## Default pager
    # PAGER=${PAGER-''}
    ## Default PDF viewer
    # R_PDFVIEWER=${R_PDFVIEWER-'open'}
    # MAKE=${MAKE-make}
    SED=${SED-sed}
    #
    CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR=C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127 
    CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB=C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/bin/x64_win64`

4. In `Environment Variables` `System Variables` `Path` I had already added:

`%CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES127%;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\bin\x64;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\bin\x86;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\bin\Pin;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\bin\GTPin;
    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;
    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
    C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
    C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
    C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin;
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-3.3.1\bin\x64;
    C:\Users\zejas\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
    C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
    C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
    C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
    C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
    C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\bin\x64_win64;
    C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include;
    C:\Rtools\bin`

5. I rebuild the package:

`C:\Users\zejas>R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual  --md5 C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI
    * checking for file 'C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
    * preparing 'cplexAPI':
    * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
    * cleaning src
    * checking vignette meta-information ... OK
    * checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
    * checking for empty or unneeded directories
    * adding MD5 file
    * building 'cplexAPI_1.3.2.tar.gz'
    Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
    Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected`

6. I attempt install of the package:

`C:\Users\zejas>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-3.3.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  INSTALL --build --no-multiarch ./cplexAPI.tar.gz
    * installing to library 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'
    * installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
    ** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include"  -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I":\Program  Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External- R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c  cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
    In file included from cplexAPI.h:26:0, from cplexAPI.c:26:
    cplexR.h:50:27: fatal error: ilcplex/cplex.h: No such file or directory
    #include <ilcplex/cplex.h>
                             ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [cplexAPI.o] Error 1
    Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f    "C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-  33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="cplexAPI.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64   OBJECTS="cplexAPI.o cplexR.o cplex_checkAPI.o cplex_longparamAPI.o init.o"' had   status 2
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
    * removing 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cplexAPI'`

## There absolutely is a `cplex.h` file in that directory!

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include\ilcplex>dir

 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0A1B-3F26
 Directory of C:\Program    Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include\ilcplex
01/09/2017  10:43 AM    <DIR>          .
01/09/2017  10:43 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,499 annotation.xsd
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            72,321 cplex.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             6,429 cplexcheck.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             1,703 cplexdistmip.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             1,857 cplexdistmipl.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             1,857 cplexdistmips.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,569 cplexdistmipx.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            76,659 cplexl.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,826 cplexremote.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,944 cplexremotel.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           111,312 cplexremotemaster.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           107,895 cplexremotemasterl.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           107,777 cplexremotemasters.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           220,496 cplexremotemasterx.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,944 cplexremotes.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             3,379 cplexremoteworker.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             3,505 cplexremoteworkerl.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             3,511 cplexremoteworkers.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             4,554 cplexremoteworkerx.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             3,289 cplexremotex.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            76,354 cplexs.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           119,712 cplexx.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            70,061 cpxconst.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM               675 ilm.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             7,158 ilocarray.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           186,959 ilocplex.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM           205,973 ilocplexi.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            13,174 iloextrmgr.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            13,496 ilogoals.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM            15,241 iloparam.h
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             5,705 solution.xsd
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             5,504 solution.xsl
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             1,397 vmc.dtd
01/09/2017  10:43 AM             2,837 vmc.xsd
34 File(s)      1,464,572 bytes
2 Dir(s)  333,053,566,976 bytes free
```

Any ideas?

---

Update with input from @c0bra and @rkersh

I update `Makevars.win`:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\lib" -lm -lcplex1270
```

Rebuild at the command line:

```
C:\Users\zejas>R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual  --md5     C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI
* checking for file 'C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'cplexAPI':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking vignette meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'cplexAPI_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
```

I attempt to install from the command line:

```
C:\Users\zejas>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-3.3.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.3.2.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
cplexAPI.c: In function 'addChannel':
cplexAPI.c:5198:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CPXaddchannel' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     newch = CPXaddchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env));
     ^
cplexAPI.c:5198:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
     newch = CPXaddchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env));
           ^
cplexAPI.c: In function 'delChannel':
cplexAPI.c:5234:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CPXdelchannel' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     CPXdelchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env), &delch);
     ^
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexR.c -o cplexR.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_checkAPI.c -o cplex_checkAPI.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_longparamAPI.c -o cplex_longparamAPI.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o cplexAPI.dll tmp.def cplexAPI.o cplexR.o cplex_checkAPI.o cplex_longparamAPI.o init.o -LC:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\lib -lm -lcplex1270 -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/lib/x64 -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcplex1270
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cplexAPI'
```

---

I edit Makevars.win

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include/lib" -lm -lcplex1270
```

I rebuild:

```
C:\Users\zejas>R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual  --md5 C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI
* checking for file 'C:\Users\zejas\Desktop\cplexAPI\cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'cplexAPI':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking vignette meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'cplexAPI_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
```

I attempt to install:

```
C:\Users\zejas>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-3.3.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD  INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.3.2.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
cplexAPI.c: In function 'addChannel':
cplexAPI.c:5198:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CPXaddchannel' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     newch = CPXaddchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env));
     ^
cplexAPI.c:5198:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
     newch = CPXaddchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env));
           ^
cplexAPI.c: In function 'delChannel':
cplexAPI.c:5234:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CPXdelchannel' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     CPXdelchannel(R_ExternalPtrAddr(env), &delch);
     ^
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexR.c -o cplexR.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_checkAPI.c -o cplex_checkAPI.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_longparamAPI.c -o cplex_longparamAPI.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o cplexAPI.dll tmp.def cplexAPI.o cplexR.o cplex_checkAPI.o cplex_longparamAPI.o init.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include/lib -lm -lcplex1270 -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/lib/x64 -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.3.1/vendor/extsoft/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/MRO-33~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcplex1270
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/zejas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cplexAPI'
```

Those are new errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks as you have left the $ signs in front of the paths in the Makevars.win file. Please try to correct to:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\lib" -lm -lcplex1270
```

edit2: As baydoganm pointed out there are two functions missing in cplex 1270. When removing those, cplexAPI compiles fine with windows, too:
[cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14845595/cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz)

Comment: I really hoped this would work.  I tried it and got the same error.  The developer of the project also in his instructions had the `$` Thank you!

Comment: In the final install output you can see that the "C" is missing in the include path (e.g., `-I":\Program  Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\include"`).  Also, in the output it looks like the other paths are using forward slashes.  These are just shots in the dark, but maybe try using `PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/Program  Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"` etc. instead in your `Makevars.win`.  Also, you could try using `C:/PROGRA~1` rather than `C:/Program  Files` there so that you don't have any spaces....

Comment: @rkersh I also had been wondering about the lack of `C` in the output and about the space.  The confusing thing is that `C` is in the input.  So I tried your idea of `C:/PROGRA~1` and also combined it with @c0bra and removed the `$`.  None of these combinations worked.  Your concern over the spaces has me wondering about the environmental variables. Thanks!

Comment: sry, i forgot to remove the "ilclplex" behind the "include"

Answer (score 2):

I have the exactly same problem and could not find a way to install the packages although tried everything similar to the post here. I am not sure if the problem is related to a version change in the CPLEX after the package is released.

Edit: I was able to confirm the problem. Apparently callable library elements addchannel, delchannel together with several others are removed in version 12.7. Here is the link:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes127/removed.html

In one of the package's source files, it has already been mentioned that "R Interface to C API of IBM ILOG CPLEX Version 12.1 to 12.6."

Looks like downgrading cplex will help.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar problem while integrating CPLEX with R, and installing the cplexAPI package, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/
there were few mistakes that I was doing, first of all, the problem arises because R does not know where IBM CPLEX is installed, so you have to manually change the file `Makevars.win` in the cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz package that is downloaded while you were trying to install cplexAPI from rstudio GUI.
look for following codes:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"${CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR}\cplex\include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"${CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB}" -lm -lcplex1261
```

two thing that you need to check is `-L"${CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB}"` is replaced by in my case, `-L"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/bin/x64_win64"` (see bin/x64_win64) , replace `$` too

second inside the folder x64_win64, look for `cplex12**.dll` file, this the file where -lcplex1261 is pointing to, here manually change -lcplex1261 to whatever your file name is (in my case it was cplex1271.dll, so I changed -lcplex1261 to -lcplex1271,

similarly `${CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR}` must be replaced by `C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271` (in my case).

After this, follow the instruction given in https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-cplex-in-r-installing-cplexapi-in-windows-10/,
essentially use the following command (from command lines) to repackage and install cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz (make sure you have Rtools installed, and make sure environment variables have PATH pointing to installation files of R, essentially taking to R.exe and Rcmd.exe for the commands to run), and

```
R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5 C:\Users{computer name here}\Desktop\cplexAPI

R CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure it out, but here is my solution:

As user3575499 already pointed out, there is a good explanation on how to install cplexAPI at https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/01/using-cplex-in-r-installing-cplexapi-in-windows-10/.

However, after following those instructions, you might get the following error:

"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated' # define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)"

The solution to this error is to add "-DBUILD_CPXSTATIC" at the end of the first line of Makevars.win, so that the file looks something like this:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"${CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR}\cplex\include" -DBUILD_CPXSTATIC
PKG_LIBS=-L"${CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB}" -lm -lcplex1261
```

After you changed that file just follow the instructions again and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

GNU R package cplexAPI: R Interface to C API of IBM ILOG CPLEX

The installation procedure for the cplexAPI package needs to know where to
find the CPLEX include directory and where to find the callable library.

I have a very large mixed integer problem to solve.   COIN‘s solver accessed through Rsymphony did a decent job, but had trouble finding feasible solutions.  I had been told that the IBM cplex  solver was the best on the market for mixed integer programming.

Installing cplex is a relatively easy task.  The difficulties began when I tried to install a link from R.  Either cplexAPI or Rcplex.  You can search and see that there is very little helpful information in the usual places.  I reached out to the developers and Jonathan of cplexAPI responded with very helpful troubleshooting and instructions.

We (honestly, all Jonathan) determined that the following sequence should correctly install cplexAPI.  First, read the directions.

1. After downloading, unpack the .tar.gz file someplace.  I am going to unpack mine on the desktop.
2. Open the newly created folder cplexAPI and you will find a directory labeled src.  Open the Makevars.win file within that folder.  I have Notepad++ installed, so I right click Makevars.win and open withNotepad++.  The instructions note that you will need to find each of these directories and type them in.  They may (and probably will if you are using any other version).

PKG_CPPFLAGS=-g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include"
PKG_LIBS=-L"C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/bin/x64_win64" -lm -lcplex1270

After saving you will need to repackage cplexAPI.  Head over to the command line (remember I unpacked my tar.gz file on my desktop) and use the command:

3.

a. goto C:\Users{{your name here}}\Documents\R\win-library\3.5

b. create a new folder called cplexAPI

c. Create another folder inside cplexAPI called libs

d. Create another folder inside libs called x64

so, you have this folder C:\Users{{your name here}}\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\cplexAPI\libs\x64

The goto the installation folder for CPLEX application C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Enterprise_Server1210\CPLEX_Studio\cplex\bin\x64_win64 and copy the file cplex12100.dll into the folder  C:\Users{{your name here}}\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\cplexAPI\libs\x64

4. R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual  --md5     C:\Users{your name here}\Desktop\cplexAPI

This will repackage the folder, avoiding the md5 error you can find while searching for solutions.  After a successful repackage you can then install the package at the command line.

5. R CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz

At this point, you may have errors.  The key you are looking for is this output:

packaged installation of 'cplexAPI' as cplexAPI_1.3.3.zip
DONE (cplexAPI)

Credit to
https://jholderieath.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/using-cplex-in-r-installing-cplexapi-in-windows-10/
https://github.com/cran/cplexAPI/blob/master/inst/INSTALL

This procedure was tested successfully with IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.10
on 64-bit Windows 10 using Rtools 3.5.

Example:

```
library(cplexAPI)
 env <- openEnvCPLEX()
 prob <- initProbCPLEX(env)
 chgProbNameCPLEX(env, prob, "sample")
nc <- 3
 nr <- 3
 obj <- c(5, 4, 3)
 rhs <- c(5, 11, 8)
 sense <- rep("L", 3)
 lb <- rep(0, 3)
ub <- rep(CPX_INFBOUND, 3)
 cn <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
 
rn <- c("q1", "q2", "q3")
beg <- c(0, 3, 6)

beg <- c(0, 3, 6)

 cnt <- rep(3, 3)
 ind <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
 val <- c(2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2)

copyLpwNamesCPLEX(env, prob, nc, nr, CPX_MAX, obj, rhs, sense, beg, cnt, ind, val, lb, ub, NULL, cn, rn)
lpoptCPLEX(env, prob)
 solutionCPLEX(env, prob)
```

https://github.com/bayesteecal/cplexAPI/blob/master/inst/INSTALL